# Invert a boolean Series will yield -1 for False and -2 for True in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a subset of Series in Pandas dataframe populated with bool value of True and False. I am trying to invert the series by using `~`.

This is the original subset of the Series.

```
7        True
8       False
14       True
38      False
72      False
...
Name: Status, Length: 197, dtype: object
```

Now I am using the following the code to invert the value.

```
mask = ~subset_df['Status']
```

I am expecting the result to be

```
7       -2
8       -1
14      -2
38      -1
72      -1
        ...

Name: Status, Length: 197, dtype: object
```

but what I really want is the following output:

```
7        False
8       True
14       False
38      True
72      True
...
Name: Status, Length: 197, dtype: object
```

I would really appreciate if you could let me know how to invert a boolean Series without converting them into -1 and -2. Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried `mask = not subset_df['Status']`?

Comment: @MarkRansom this is the error message is using not ```ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```

Comment: This has been the root cause of so many problems for me - good spot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, you have a series of `object` dtype, filled with what are probably ordinary Python `bool`s. Applying `~` to such a series goes through elementwise and applies the ordinary `~` operator to each element, and ordinary Python bools inherit `~` from `int` - they do not perform logical negation for this operation.

You can convert your series to boolean dtype first before applying `~` to get logical negation:

```
~series.astype(bool)
```

On a sufficiently recent Pandas version (1.0 and up), you may wish to instead use the new [nullable boolean dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/boolean.html) with `astype('boolean')` instead of `astype(bool)`.

You should also figure out *why* your series has object dtype in the first place - it's likely that the correct place to address this issue is somewhere earlier in your code, not here. Perhaps you built it wrong, or you tried to use NaN or None to represent missing values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replace function of pandas Series as:

```
subset_df['Status'].replace(to_replace=[True, False], value=[False, True])
```

This will return another series with replaced values. But if you want to change the actual dataframe, then you can add a parameter 'inplace=True' as:

```
subset_df['Status'].replace(to_replace=[True, False], value=[False, True], inplace=True)
```

Comment: thank you so much. The replace method indeed creates the opposite values in the Series, but is there anyway I can use a mask? Coz my next step is to do ```incorrect= subset_df[mask][['a', 'b']].copy()```

Comment: Thanks! If you liked my answer, then please upvote it. And sorry! I don't know what is mask in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
If `Status` column is `object/string` type. Here we are checking if the `Status` value is `True` then we are replacing it with `False` and `False string` with `True`.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'Status':['True', 'False', 'True', 'False', 'False']
})
df.Status = np.where(df['Status']=='True',False,True)
df
```

**Output**

```
    Status
0   False
1   True
2   False
3   True
4   True
```

If `series` is of `boolean type`, then below options can be followed.

```
s = pd.Series([True, False, True, False, False])
```

**Two options**

```
-s
```

or

```
np.invert(s)
```

**Output**

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

What you tried works for df as well

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'Status':[True, False, True, False, False]
})
df['Status'] = ~df['Status']
df
```

**Output**

```
    Status
0   False
1   True
2   False
3   True
4   True
```

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion. Not sure why but when using ```-s``` or ```np.invert(s)```, the output will still be ```dtype = object``` instead of bool. And then if I am applying the following function ```incorrect= subset_df[mask][['a', 'b']].copy()```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([-1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,\n            ...\n             0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],\n           dtype='int64', length=197)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: okay, seems like `Status` column is `object` type and not boolean type. Updated the answer to support that.

Comment: that makes sense, just wondering why we are writing the logic like this ```np.where(df['Status']=='True',False,True)```

Comment: Also I think ```df.Status = np.where(df['Status']=='True',False,True)``` will only work if the type is string but not Object. Because when the type is object and the comparison with 'True' will always be False.

Comment: Updated the explanation for `np.where`  in the solution. This solution will work with both `string and object` type. I will let you explore similarities between `string and object` in pandas.

Comment: I do think the comparison with string True will not work. ```
7        True
8       False
14      False
38      False
72      False
Name: Status, Length: 197, dtype: object
7       False
8       False
14      False
38      False
72      False
Name: Status, Length: 197, dtype: bool``` Everything will evaluate to be False